# How to implement forgot password feature in any Sitecore application

Tags: security, authentication

When a user forgets his password, he/she can click on forgot password link which will trigger an email with password reset link.

How to implement this functionality in a Sitecore application? Since Sitecore is using ASP.NET Membership provider, is there any methods to generate password reset token with expiration ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Disclosure: answer taken from [Securing the password recovery experience in Sitecore 8](https://laubplusco.net/securing-password-recovery-experience-sitecore-8/) by *Anders Laub Christofferson*

First we do some configuration re-organizing.

We copy paste the old `passwordRecovery` pipeline and call the new one `confirmedPasswordRecovery`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
      <processors>
      <confirmPasswordRecovery argsType="Sitecore.Pipelines.PasswordRecovery.PasswordRecoveryArgs">
        <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PasswordRecovery.VerifyUsername, Sitecore.Kernel" />
        <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PasswordRecovery.GeneratePassword, Sitecore.Kernel" />
        <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PasswordRecovery.PopulateMail, Sitecore.Kernel" />
        <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PasswordRecovery.SendPasswordRecoveryMail, Sitecore.Kernel" />
      </confirmPasswordRecovery>
      </processors>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

We replace the `GeneratePassword` with a processor called `GenerateToken` for generating and storing a token on the user profile:

```
public class GenerateToken : PasswordRecoveryProcessor
{
  public override void Process(PasswordRecoveryArgs args)
  {
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
    var user = User.FromName(args.Username, true);
    if (user == null)
    {
      args.AbortPipeline();
      return;
    }
    var token = ID.NewID.ToShortID().ToString();
    StoreTokenOnUser(user, token);
    args.CustomData.Add(Constants.ConfirmTokenKey, token);
  }

  private void StoreTokenOnUser(User user, string confirmToken)
  {
    user.Profile.SetCustomProperty(Constants.ConfirmTokenKey, confirmToken);
    user.Profile.Save();
  }
}
```

To make this work you need to add a field called PasswordToken on the user profile

```
internal struct Constants
{
  internal const string ConfirmTokenKey = "PasswordToken";
}
```

And then we replace `PopulateMail` with `PopulateConfirmMail` that populates a html email with a confirm link.

```
public class PopulateConfirmMail : PopulateMail
{
  public override void Process(PasswordRecoveryArgs args)
  {
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
    var token = args.CustomData[Constants.ConfirmTokenKey] as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
      return;
    var confirmLink = GenerateConfirmLink(token, args.Username);
    args.SendFromDisplayName = "Sitecore website";
    args.SendFromEmail = "donotreply@mysitecoresite.net";
    args.Subject = "Confirm password recovery";
    var user = User.FromName(args.Username, false);
    args.HtmlEmailContent = GetHtmlEmailContent(user, confirmLink);
  }

  protected virtual string GenerateConfirmLink(string token, string userName)
  {
    var serverUrl = StringUtil.EnsurePostfix('/', WebUtil.GetServerUrl());
    return serverUrl + "sitecore/api/passwordrecovery/confirm/" + userName.Replace('\\', '|') + "/" + token;
  }

  protected virtual string GetHtmlEmailContent(User user, string confirmLink)
  {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("<html><head><title>");
    sb.AppendLine("Sitecore password recovery");
    sb.AppendLine("</title></head><body>");
    sb.AppendLine("<h1>Please confirm</h1>");
    sb.AppendLine("<p>Hi " + user.Profile.FullName + ",<br/></p>");
    sb.AppendLine("<p>Please follow the link below to recover your password</p>");
    sb.AppendLine("<a href=\"" + confirmLink + "\">" + confirmLink + "</a>");
    sb.AppendLine("</body>");
    sb.AppendLine("</html>");
    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

Notice the confirm link that we create, this is for a `ApiController` with a `HttpGet` method that expects a username and a token.

```
public class ConfirmRecoveryController : ApiController
{
  [HttpGet]
  public IHttpActionResult Confirm(string userName, string token)
  {
    userName = userName.Replace('|', '\\');
    var user = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(userName, true);
    if (user == null || !TokenIsValid(user, token))
      return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, this);

    var passwordRecoveryArgs = new PasswordRecoveryArgs(HttpContext.Current)
    {
      Username = userName
    };
    Pipeline.Start("confirmPasswordRecovery", passwordRecoveryArgs);
    if (!passwordRecoveryArgs.Aborted)
      DeleteToken(user);

    return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, this);
  }

  private void DeleteToken(User user)
  {
    user.Profile.SetCustomProperty(Constants.ConfirmTokenKey, string.Empty);
    user.Profile.Save();
  }

  private bool TokenIsValid(User user, string token)
  {
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) && ShortID.IsShortID(token) && TokenExists(user, token);
  }

  private bool TokenExists(User user, string confirmToken)
  {
    var tokenOnProfile = user.Profile.GetCustomProperty(Constants.ConfirmTokenKey);
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenOnProfile) && tokenOnProfile.Equals(confirmToken, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
  }
}
```

This controller executes the new (old) `confirmPasswordRecovery` pipeline, then deletes the token and redirects to the login page.

We need to register the route so we create a processor for the initialize pipeline:

```
public class RegisterHttpRoutes
{
  public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
  {
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Configure);
  }

  protected void Configure(HttpConfiguration configuration)
  {
    var routes = configuration.Routes;
    routes.MapHttpRoute("PasswordRecovery_Confirm", "sitecore/api/passwordrecovery/{action}/{userName}/{token}", new
    {
      controller = "ConfirmRecovery",
      action = "Index"
    });
  }
}
```

And patch it into the initialize pipeline:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.EnsureAnonymousUsers, Sitecore.Kernel']"
          type="LaubPlusCo.PasswordRecovery.Infrastructure.RegisterHttpRoutes, LaubPlusCo.PasswordRecovery" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

And the password recovery mail is the standard one that you can modify in the core database on the item `/sitecore/system/Settings/Security/Password recovery/Password Recovery Email`

Link to blog post [here](https://laubplusco.net/securing-password-recovery-experience-sitecore-8/)

**Update:**

If you want to have token expiration functionality, you need to add to Custom User Profile new field like `Created`, where you will store token created `DateTime` value and when user will click link in email, you need to check this value with your condition.

Comment: How could you do this in Sitecore 7.1? Since the PasswordRecovery doesn't exist